# moved TYPO3 installation to a server at a different timezone - all dates offseted

Tags: timezone, typo3

I moved a TYPO3 4.7.7 (MySQL) installation from a server at GMT+1 to a server at GMT+2.

Now all pages which display a date and time have the following difference:

old server:

```
<p>published: 03 Dec 2012 – 12:00</p>
```

new server:

```
<p>published: 03 Dec 2012 – 13:00</p>
```

I've tried altering the timezone offset via `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['phpTimeZone']` and `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['serverTimeZone']` but nothing happened even after clearing all caches.

Note that obviously I don't want to change the system's (linux) time or timezone settings.

Where should I look next?

Comment: how many records displaying that you have? maybe it will be better to modify all timestamps in DB instead forcing the offset. If you'll force it, remember that it will require to convert the time ... every time, changing DB you'll do it only once.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is this:

typoscript:

```
strftime.GMT = 2
```

from: http://www.typo3.net/forum/beitraege/extensions_schreiben/106541/

Answer (score 0):

Set the PHP time zone for TYPO3.

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['phpTimeZone'] = 'Europe/Berlin';

Set the server time zone for TYPO3.

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['serverTimeZone'] = '1';

Modify the output of the field tstamp in the TYPO3 tt_content and in the TYPO3 extensions:

```
if (!empty($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['serverTimeZone'])) {
    $row['tstamp'] += ($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['serverTimeZone'] * 3600);
}
```

This is in the folder /typo3/sysext/cms/tslib/content:

class.tslib_content_content.php
before the line `$this->cObj->lastChanged($row['tstamp']);`

class.tslib_content_records.php
before the line `$this->cObj->lastChanged($row['tstamp']);`